# Ploting a topology that accepts saddle point in 3 dimensional plot

Tags: plotting

In order to visualize a saddle point, a common example given by Wikipedia is $z=x^2-y^2$.

```
Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

I would like to have a 3d figure which shows the saddle value nicely. For example the above given figure is nice. But the function which is plotted ($x^2 - y^2$ in the above given example) must get only values between $0$ and $1$. Additionally $x$ must also get only real values between $0$ and $1$. If $y$ can also get values in $0$ and $1$ it will be nicer but this condition is not required; $y>0$ is enough. Is it possible to get a nice saddle point figure?

What I tried was to scale the above given figure. Then I was able to scale $x^2 - y^2$ to $0$, $1$ but the $x$ and $y$ were not as I wanted. $x^2 - y^2$ is also not a must, it can be any function which is convex in x and concave in y and convexity and concavity is curvy, namely not linear so that the figure will seem beautifully.

How to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is very hard to understand. I have interpreted it to mean that you have a function $f:[x_0,x_1]\times[y_0,y_1]\to[f_0,f_1]$, and you want a similar function that lies in $[0,1]\times[0,1]\to[0,1]$.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 - y^2;
{x0, x1} = {-5, 5};
{y0, y1} = {-5, 5};
{f0, f1} = {-25, 25};
g[x_, y_] := Rescale[f[Rescale[x, {0, 1}, {x0, x1}],
                       Rescale[y, {0, 1}, {y0, y1}]], 
                     {f0, f1}, {0, 1}];
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your guess is completely correct. It means the question was not that bad. However, I still need to know what is the scaled function. Assume you will present this to some people. They will ask what is x axis what is y axis and what is z axis. What must one say?

Comment: "It means the question was not that bad." No, look at what I said: *The question is very hard to understand.* Just because I managed it after a fair bit of effort and luck does not mean that it was not hard.

Comment: Very good work. Thanks alot. One question: why do I have bluelike colors in my plot while your plot has golden colors? I have mathematica 9 on an xp 32 bit machine, if necessary.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Your Mma version could be the reason. By adding the option "PlotStyle -> Blue" to `Plot3D[]` you can change it (to blue, in this case).
Or use the Option "ColorFunction" ... for further details you can look it up in the help section.

Answer (score 3):

I can just guess what you mean:

Is it something like this you want to do?

```
surface = Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> None];
Manipulate[
 Show[{
   surface,
   Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, xi}, {y, 0, yi}],
   Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0, 0^2 - 0^2}]}],
   Graphics3D[{Green, PointSize[Large], Point[{xi, yi, xi^2 - yi^2}]}]
   }],
 {{xi, .5}, .01, 1}, {{yi, 2}, .01, 5}]
```

You can manipulate the "filled surface" to show where the saddle point is.

[image]

EDIT: Just added points. The red one always shows the saddle point.